# How to prevent all Internet activity from computer while allowing intranet activity?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, internet, intranet

I'm trying to get my computer to act like our build server, which has no internet connection.

I can't simply unplug the cable, because it is necessary to have access to the intranet for the work that I'm doing.

What is the simplest way to block all requests to the outside world?

I'm using a Lenovo laptop with Windows XP.

Comment: Replicate whatever happens to the build server to prevent it from connecting to the internet.

Comment: @afrazier if you are trying to help, it didn't work because: 1) I have know idea what that is. 2) The build server runs Linux, not XP. Maybe you'll have to connect the dots for me.

Answer (score 2):

Setup firewall - forbid access to all ip addresses except for those from your local network.

Answer (score 1):

Set your default gateway to a host/device that does not exist?

Comment: +1: The simpliest solutions are often the most effective.